# Strange Javascript & Mod_Rewrite issue

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a soundplayer active on my website

```
http://replay.rhr.fm/artist.php?artist=name
```

As you can see the playlist is only included once,
Now when you call the same page with the use of htaccess, it included the playlist twice.

```
http://replay.rhr.fm/artist/name
```

The .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^artist/([^/]*)$ /artist.php?artist=$1 [L]
```

I don't quite understand what the difference is for the javascript to decide to append the playlist twice.

What exactly am I doing wrong with this .htaccess script?

Comment: Where is the **playlist** in your url? i cant see it

Comment: Playlist is on the page, When the system is ready it will dynamically load a playlist depending on artist.php?[ "NAME" ]

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Open up the first link, And then the second link. Both are exactly the same php files that are beeing executed (artist.php), If you call  rhr.fm/artist.php?artist=name you will get the playlist once, when you call rhr.fm/artist/name the playlist will be placed on the page twice.

Comment: Both those URLs produce the same page for me. But there appears to be some kind of client-side redirect to the document root? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your .htaccess directive?